# Using Jquery for multiple values?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to display a reply form for each comment but I hide the form using Jquery and I was wondering how can I grab the comment id and add it to Jquery so it can hide each reply form and display the correct reply form correctly instead of displaying the wrong reply form?

For example, `form_show_hide1, form_show_hide2, form_show_hide3, form_show_hide4` and so on.

I;m using PHP and JQuery.

Here is the Jquery code.

```
  $(function(){
      $('a#form_show_hide').click(function(){
        $('#form_container').slideToggle('slow');
        // prevent default action
        return false;
      });
    });
```

Here is the HTML code. Note I changed the ids to classes.

```
<a href="#" title="Reply Link" class="form_show_hide">Reply</a>


<form method="post" action="' .htmlentities($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) . '" class="form_container>
    <fieldset>
        <textarea rows="6" cols="70"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="reply" value="Submit" />
        <input type="hidden"  name="id" value="' . urlencode($comment_id) . '"  />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you post the markup? It seems you're re-using IDs which is going to cause trouble, it's best to use a class and find the element you want relatively.

Comment: the code would be to big to post here on SO. so how would I use classes with my Jquery code?

Comment: You don't need to post unrelated content, code and markup. Just the shortest possible code snippet which represents the case and exhibits the problem is more than enough. See also http://sscce.org.

Comment: Just post a snippet, one section containing comment and reply for example, so we can see how they relate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by finding the `.form_container` element relatively using [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('a.form_show_hide').click(function(){
    $(this).next('.form_container').slideToggle('slow');
    return false;
  });
});
```

There's spacing in your code which gives me doubts though.  If they're siblings but not *immediate* siblings use [`.nextAll('.form_container:first')`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) rather than the [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) call.

If they're not siblings but are in some sort of parent container you can identify, for example:

```
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <a href="#" title="Reply Link" class="form_show_hide">Reply</a>
  </div>
  <form method="post" action="' .htmlentities($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) . '" class="form_container>
    <fieldset>
      <textarea rows="6" cols="70"></textarea>
      <input type="submit" name="reply" value="Submit" />
      <input type="hidden"  name="id" value="' . urlencode($comment_id) . '"  />
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Then go up to that container and back down, replacing the [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) call with `.closest('.container').find('.form_container')`.  [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) just needs a selector to identify that parent container correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("SELECT_YOUR_FORMS").each(function(index) {
    $(this).DO_YOUR_FUNCTION();
  });
```